# Read only the numbers in a specified line in a text file

Tags: python, file, floating-point, readfile

I am trying to read two floats from lines 18 and 19 of a text file and find their average. Please only look at the section of code separated by `#########`.

The file has a mixture of words and numbers, and I don't know how to just read the numbers.  An example of what line 18 and 19 would look like is:

```
TM-score= 0.27878 (if normalized by length of Chain_1)
TM-score= 0.36068 (if normalized by length of Chain_2)
```

```
def tmval(self,name,tmvalpath):
    dir = tmvalpath
    splits = []
    avg = 0
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        file_name2, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        n1,n2,align = file_name2.split('_')
        n = ('{}_{}'.format(n1,n2))
        if n == name:
#####################################################
            with open(os.path.join(dir,f)) as file:
                for i, line in enumerate(file):
                    if i == 17:
                       #retrieve data from 18th line
                       number1 =
                    elif i == 18:
                       # retrieve data from 19th line
                       number2 = 
######################################################
  avg = float(number1 + number2)/2                      
  return avg
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show also your input file. *A mixture of words and numbers* isn't enough detail. We can't reproduce your problem without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

with open(os.path.join(dir,f)) as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i == 17:
            number1 = float(re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', line).group())

        elif i == 18:
            number2 = float(re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', line).group())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like job for regulear expression.

Something like [0-9][.][0-9]* should do it.

Python:

```
import re
import numpy as np

line = 'TM-score= 0.36068 (if normalized by length of Chain_2)'

str = re.search(r'[0-9][.][0-9]*', line)
number1 = float(str.group(0))
print(number1)
```

Comment: You should avoid using `str` as a variable name.